# Unlicensed User without Office Plan with PowerBI license

Tags: active-directory, powerbi, office365, exchange-server

I work for a company where we started to share the PowerBI license for users without the Office plan. They started asking us to give them access to the Outlook to be in touch with newsletters and other reports from PowerBI. Our organization is not allowing to supply an Office license to PowerBI users.

I have a few questions :

1. Is there a chance to forward emails to their private mailboxes without converting them to SharedMailbox?
2. if I add a PowerBI license with Office plan and convert it to shared the PowerBI will be disabled on that account? If not is it possible to take it off or do I need to convert it to the regular mailbox to take it off?
3. I know about Mail Flow rules, are they safe to use? They are global rules either way.
4. I am excluding here a Contact user with one reason PowerBI license cannot be added to a Contact user.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer,
Create AD account synch it with O365 move it to correct OU, 
go to the user created earlier -> Attribute Editor -> Attribute: targetAddress add: SMTP:youraddress@something.com

Wait to synch and test. All emails should be redirected to the target address without having the license.

Comment: Excellent. This trick can be used in a LOT of use case with « external user » thanks